# How to get the Array Index Value and showing them in label in collection view

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uilabel, nsmutablearray

i taking photos and showing them in scrolling part in collection view.i want to show the numbers like if that collection view has one image , i want to show 1.if there are 3 three images then i need to show 3,2, 1,for corresponding images .because I'm adding the latest picture at first .the numbering should be descending .Please help me to do this.
wat i did is ..

```
  NSUInteger index;
  for (id item in self.myimagearray)
  {
     index = [[self.myimagearray indexOfObject:self.myimagearray];

    NSLog(@" the index are:%lu",(unsigned long)index);
    Cell.waterMark_lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)index];
   }
```

and it showing the count like 3 in all images .Please help me do this ..

Comment: you should not fast enumerate and set cell text. you should have the array looped by the delegate method indexpath.row .

Comment: Can u please give sample @ Teja Nandamuri

Comment: do you want to show the image number with your image, if it is what you need, you can do it inside the `delegate` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**note :you have to use custom collection view cell.**

1. create a `custom collection view cell` with a `label` and with a `image view`.
2. Then create `IBOutlet` s to `custom collection view cell class` ,`.h` file.
3. then call for `collection view delegate methods.` like below.

> ```
> -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
> {
>     return 1;
> }
>
> -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
> {
>     return  [self.yourarray count];
> }
>
> -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
> {
>         MyCutomCollectionViewCell *thecell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"your_cell_identifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
>
> //this is how you can get the index path to string
> NSString *the_index_path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)indexPath.row];
>
>
> //then bind it to your label
> thecell.mylabel.text = the_index_path;
>
> //and bind your image data here
>
>
> }
> ```